# Java Google datastore async calls

Tags: java, asynchronous, google-cloud-datastore

I do not want to block threads in my application and so I am wondering are calls to the the Google Datastore async? For example the docs show something like this to retrieve an entity:

```
// Key employeeKey = ...;
LookupRequest request = LookupRequest.newBuilder().addKey(employeeKey).build();
LookupResponse response = datastore.lookup(request);
if (response.getMissingCount() == 1) {
  throw new RuntimeException("entity not found");
}
Entity employee = response.getFound(0).getEntity();
```

This does not look like an async call to me, so it is possible to make aysnc calls to the database in Java? I noticed App engine has some libraries for async calls in its Java API, but I am not using appengine, I will be calling the datastore from my own instances. As well, if there is an async library can I test it on my local server (for example app engine's async library I could not find a way to set it up to use my local server for example I this library can't get my environment variables).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your shoes, I'd give a try to Spotify's open-source [Asynchronous Google Datastore Client](https://github.com/spotify/async-datastore-client) -- I have not personally tried it, but it appears to meet all of your requirements, including being able to test on your local server. Please give it a try and let us all know how well it meets your needs, so we can all benefit and learn -- thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the link! Yes this looks like exactly what I am looking for can't believe I didn't find it earlier. O will give it a try soon.

Comment: @user2924127, since it's a third-party open source product, first committed less than six months ago, it's hardly surprising, nor any blame to you!, that you had not heard of it yet. Hey, as I mention, I didn't actually *try* it myself yet...:-).

Comment: Hi Alex, I have a question that you may be able to answer. For the parameters 'ACCOUNT' and 'KEYPATH' what do I put here if I am running locally? I have not signed up with the cloud yet do I need to sign up to be able to run locally? I tried omitting this method or inserting empty text, but it did not work.

Comment: I have not explored this in depth, but in the pom.xml both account and keypath properties are just spaces -- yet that seems OK for running local tests.

Comment: I had tried to replicate this previously, but it did not work.